# Importance of semi-positive definiteness of covariance matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix

Since Covariance matrix is symmetric it is Hermitian (self adjoint) and always diagonalizable. If the matrix has all non zero eigen-values its is a full rank matrix. But what is the importance of the covariance matrix being positive definite?

I am asking this question in context of principle component analysis. We often come across the statement that covariance matrix is positive semi-definite and also the proof for it. The proof and information are nice to know. But, by not being able to figure out its importance in given context i feel I am missing some important point. 
For example the importance of positive definiteness of a kernel is often stated clearly that a positive definite kernel corresponds to a RKHS. But what is the importance of positive definiteness of covariance matrix.

Comment: While waiting for more experienced people chime in, the importance is such that the eigenvalues will be positive and the eigenvectors will be real. I have hard time imagining my data being projected on same imaginary basis. The positive eigenvalues tell us which directions account for that percentage of variance (or energy); the real eigenvectors are the directions on which the data can be mapped to when doing dimensionality reduction.